# Passing obejct to function and assigning null , won't change the object in Main()

Tags: c#, function, object, pass-by-value

Consider this code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Foo
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public String y { get; set; }

        public Foo()
        {
            this.x = 1;
            this.y = "Jack";
        }
    }

    class Testing
    {
        public static void funcChange(Foo bar)
        {
            bar.x = 2;
            bar.y = "Inga";
        }

        public static void funcNull(Foo bar)
        {
            bar = null;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            Foo foo2 = foo;

            // let's change foo 
            Console.WriteLine("foo before:" + foo.x + " " + foo.y);  // 1 Jack
            funcChange(foo);
            Console.WriteLine("foo after:" + foo.x + " " + foo.y);  // 2 Inga

            // let's null the foo object
            Console.WriteLine("foo before:" + foo.x + " " + foo.y);  // 2 Inga
            funcNull(foo);
            Console.WriteLine("foo after:" + foo.x + " " + foo.y);  // 2 Inga

        }


    }
}
```

When I run `funcChange` , then foo changes from `1 Jack` to `2 Inga` .

When I run `funcNull` , then foo keeps `2 Inga` even after I null foo in `funcNull` .

From my understanding , C# passing objects by value (I'm not referring to `out` or `ref` !!!) .

If so , then why when I run `funcChange` on `foo` , then its contents is changing , but when I run 
`funcNull` , the `foo` instance still points to `2 Inga` ?

Much appreciated

Comment: Please read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Downvoters : Feel free to downvote ... I don't see the reason but help yourselves .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C# does pass by value by default, however in

```
funcChange(Foo bar)
```

bar is a reference to an object of type `Foo`. This reference is a copy of the input argument, however it refers to the same object on the managed heap. This is why you can mutate `bar` in `funcChange`.

In `funcNull`,

```
bar = null;
```

sets the local variable `bar` to null. Since `bar` is a copy of the input argument, it does not affect `foo` in the caller.

Answer (score 2):

your method should be

```
    public static void funcNull(ref Foo bar)
    {
        bar = null;
    }
```

and call it like so:

```
        funcNull(ref foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

*`From my understanding , C# passing objects by value (I'm not referring to out or ref !!!) .`*

no  all class  objects are reference  types.
But you shouldn't  confuse the concept of [`passing by reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) with the concept of reference types.
if  you  declare your method like this you should be able to change the underlying  argument variable

```
public static void funcNull(ref Foo bar)
        {
            bar = null;
        }
```

Comment: That doesn't change the *object* - it changes the *variable* used for the argument in the calling code. It's important to distinguish between variables and objects.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this;

```
public static Foo funcNull(Foo bar)
    {
        bar = null;
        return bar;
    }



foo = funcNull(foo);
```

When I run the program there's a runtime error saying that foo doesn't exist when I try to write its values.
So this method works.

[image]